# Replace quotes but keep inches

Tags: php, regex

I have text like: Senkatel Maximus 10.1" "White"

I would like to strip the quotes but keep the quote in the inch specification 10.1"

I tried using regex but it does not support variable length negative lookaheads

**This:** `Senkatel Maximus 10.1" "White"`

**Should become:** `Senkatel Maximus 10.1" White`

I need it as a general solution to stripping quotes without killing the inches in the text, so things like `Senkatel Maximus 10.1" "Moonlight blue"` and `"Senkatel Maximus 10.1""` should also work if possible.

Comment: My answer should be at least a step in the right direction, if you take a look.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes it is, thank you for providing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might try this one:

```
"(\S(?:\s(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"|[^"])+\S)"
```

and replace with `$1`.

I tested it on some of the samples lying about. [regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/xV6gC1).

EDIT:

If you have to remove quotes from strings like `Dims: A" x B"` as well (i.e. only numbers followed by double quotes have to be kept, unless in situations like `"Film: 300"`, then you can use a regex a bit like SmokeyPHP's and adding a part I made above to give this:

```
(^|[^0-9])"((\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?"|[^"])+)"
```

Some samples have been tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/kU6gN8). (Note the `\n` were added on the demo because the regex was being tested on several strings and can be removed when testing on a string by string basis).

Comment: I really like the way it sounds, could you add your explanation to the answer?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen But shouldn't the first be left as is? For the second one, I know the regex works for at least 3 characters between quotes, so maybe adding an `or` just for stuff under 3 chars: [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/aA3xY2)

Comment: no, in `Dims: A" x B"` there are no inches so the quotes have to be removed, unless I don't know something and A" is an inch. I guess people might use roman numerals for inches `IV"` but I haven't ever seen that

Comment: @TimoHuovinen That's a really strange way of quoting things if you ask me! In that case, I can work out something derived from SmokeyPHP's regex and add the bit I came up with to give [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/sJ1wR8) (Note that I added `\n` in the negated classes because I'm testing a bunch of lines at a time, when you will test individual lines, you can drop them). How is it now? :)

Comment: it is great now! But please keep the one you have now too, in case someone wants to do some more sane quote removal. And yes, I do agree about the strange quotes, I am getting these quotes from a website XML and when I noticed that they had inches mixed in I was terrified.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Great! And yep, sure I rarely remove the initial content in my answers for updated ones unless they are completely off xD.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the job can be done with

```
preg_replace('/"(\S*?)"/', '$1', $string);
```

This removes the quotes from around any non-whitespace part of the string. Assuming at least one whitespace character appears between a single quote (which should remain) and any pairs of quotes (which should be removed) and also that the pairs of quotes do not include any whitespace it should work fine.

Comment: @Itay: I was just editing to point that out. I don't see how it could work in all cases because you need *something* to serve as the indication that a quote is single vs one of a legitimate pair. I chose "no whitespace in between" as the attribute that distinguishes pairs. If that is a problem for the OP then we 'd need to find something else.

Comment: For example, if I had used `/"(.*?)(?<!\d)"/` then someone would have said "does not work with `"Foo 23"`" etc. It cannot work with *everything* unless you write a full-fledged parser.

Comment: @Jon even a parser might choke on things like `XYZ Size 3" x 5"` as [x4rf41](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18696424/175071) mentioned

Answer (score 2):

The following works for most situations mentioned on this page:

```
$newStr = preg_replace('#(^|[^0-9])"([^"]+)"#','$1$2',$str);
```

(Some) Test results:

```
"test" Senkatel "woo69" 2"-5" Maximus 10.1" "White"
test Senkatel woo69 2"-5" Maximus 10.1" White

Product: "Senkatel Maximus 10.1""
Product: Senkatel Maximus 10.1"

Dims: 4" x 6"
Dims: 4" x 6"

"Film: 300"
Film: 300
```

Issues will arise if there are inches in the middle of the string such as
 `"Senkatel 10.1" Maximus"` - at which point a much more complex set of code is required. This is probably the simplest code for the most function.

Answer (score 2):

this removes any qoute that isnt directly after a number

```
preg_replace('/([^0-9])"/', '$1', $string);
```

but if the text is something like this: `Senkatel Maximus 10.1" "White 1000"`
it would become: `Senkatel Maximus 10.1" White 1000"`

it just really hard to distinguish between a number withing quotes and an inch specification

Comment: I see, why did they have to use quotes for inches!! gah!

Comment: Well, this regex works for everything besides quoted numbers (it works for all the examples you posted). but actually parsing is also a problem. think about this: `XYZ Size 3" x 5"` it does mean 3 inch by 5 inch but there is an opening and closing quote, parsing it would be really hard

Comment: I see, I didn't think of `XYZ Size 3" x 5"` but you are right.

Comment: A space before the first quote `XYZ Size 3" x 5"` could be used as the indicator that it is an inch, compare: `XYZ Size 3" x 5"` and `XYZ Size 3 " x 5"`